# Combine all subsequent rows having the same value for one variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 value = round(runif(20)*10))

# output
   group value
1      c    10
2      c     7
3      c     7
4      b     5
5      c     6
6      b     3
7      b     1
8      b    10
9      c     9
10     a     7
11     b     8
12     b     0
13     a     5
14     b     8
15     c     2
16     a     3
17     c     2
18     c     1
19     a     4
20     a     4
```

And I want to sum up `value` for all rows with the same `group`, but only if these rows are subsequent. The expected output would be:

```
# output
   group values
1      c     24
2      b      5
3      c      6
4      b     14
5      c      9
6      a      7
7      b      8
8      a      5
9      b      8
10     c      2
11     a      3
12     c      3
13     a      8
```

I considered using `lag()`, but then I would need to know how often a group can occur subsequently. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by consecutive values with `dplyr::consecutive_id` or `data.table::rleid`:

With **dplyr**:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(group)) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value), .by = c(id, group)) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

---

In **data.table**:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(group = first(group), value = sum(value)), by = rleid(group)][, rleid := NULL][]
```

---

A third option to create the grouping is with `lag` and `cumsum`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(lag(group, default = "not a letter") != group))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `group_by(id, group) %>% summarise(value = sum(value))` equivalent to `summarise(value = sum(value), .by = c(id, group))`? I want to use `summarize_if()` but it does not let me use `.by`.

Comment: Yes it's the same, .by is a more recent function. note that `summarize_if` is deprecated. Use `across` rather.

Comment: Small point, but on large data `group = first(group)` could be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `rle`

```
with(
  df,
  {
    x <- rle(group)
    x$lengths <- by(value, rep(seq_along(x$lengths), x$lengths), sum)
    setNames(rev(list2DF(x)), names(df))
  }
)
```

gives

```
   group value
1      c    24
2      b     5
3      c     6
4      b    14
5      c     9
6      a     7
7      b     8
8      a     5
9      b     8
10     c     2
11     a     3
12     c     3
13     a     8
```

Comment: @dww Now I changed my solution to base R to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Similar approach with `aggregate` `aggregate(value ~ group, transform(df, group = inverse.rle(within.list(rle(group), values <- seq_along(values)))), sum)`

Comment: @akrun great to see `aggregate`, thank you my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Using naked R I would create a new column that detects group change, split on that and calculate whatever you want after that.

```r
set.seed(123)
xy <- data.frame(group = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 value = round(runif(20)*10))

spl <- rle(xy$group)

xy$int_groups <- rep(1:length(spl$values), times = spl$lengths)

xy.split <- split(x = xy, f = xy$int_groups)

out <- lapply(X = xy.split, FUN = function(x) {
  data.frame(group = unique(x$group), values = sum(x$value))
})

do.call(rbind, out)

   group values
1      c     24
2      b      5
3      c      6
4      b     14
5      c      9
6      a      7
7      b      8
8      a      5
9      b      8
10     c      2
11     a      3
12     c      3
13     a      8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another *naked R* alternative:

```
poor_rleid <- \(x) cumsum(x != c("", head(x, -1L)))
data.frame(
  group = rle(df$group)$values,
  value = split(df$value, poor_rleid(df$group)) |> sapply(sum)
)
)
#    group value
# 1      c    24
# 2      b     5
# 3      c     6
# 4      b    14
# 5      c     9
# 6      a     7
# 7      b     8
# 8      a     5
# 9      b     8
# 10     c     2
# 11     a     3
# 12     c     3
# 13     a     8
```